# Access Denied, You are not authorized to access this page

Tags: php, drupal

Iam getting the Error : **You are not authorized to access this page.**
when i try to load the admin page since iam also unable to see the login page, please help me solving this.
Can see the screen shot aswell.
[image]

Comment: why can you not see the login page? do you believe you should have access to the page mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, Else how come the admin can login to the drupal dashboard?

Comment: I can see the login page - are you saying that you cannot?

Comment: yes iam unable to see in mine... i cleared cache and tried aswell....but couldnt figure it

Comment: how many browsers have u tried?

Comment: i tried in mozilla, chrome, safari, opera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login page is working well:

http://currentconservation.org/user

If you can't see it try clearing cookies for that domain.
Or did you maybe added some records in your machine host file so normal DNS server is not used? Try opening login page from another computer.
Or try visiting

http://currentconservation.org/user/logout

Maybe you are already logged in with some strange user account...

Comment: You must first login and then use admin pages. That's not login page.